# GetAllValues from datatview in a webix

Tags: datatable, webix

how to get all values from dataview in a webix,
this still doesn't work by me, because the table is not to be selected

```
var data = $$('experienceTable');
console.log(data.getSelectedId())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get some specific record

```
console.log(data.getItem(id));
```

And to get all records

```
console.log(data.serialize())
```